Is there a way to pull an object's assigned material into Geometry Nodes?
The Geometry Nodes system includes a "Set Material" node which assigns a specified material to selected geometry. Is there any way to do the opposite and 'Get Material', as it were? That is, a node (or group of nodes) that takes some input geometry and outputs the material already assigned to it?
Context: I'm using Geometry Nodes (GN) to create some geometry, and I want to have different instances of that geometry with different materials that can be easily swapped around. The intuitive thing to me would be to have simple mesh objects (let's say a bunch of cubes); assign the desired material to each cube instance; apply the same GN setup to each cube to create the instanced geometry; and inside that GN setup, pull the assigned material from the Group Input node's Geometry slot and link that to a Set Material node at the end of the geometry-generating node-tree. Then I would be able to change the material on each base object from the Shading view and have it populate through the GN setup automatically.
Without a 'Get Material' node, the current workflow around this involves lots of jumping back and forth between the Shading and Geometry Nodes views and the Modifiers and Material panels, which is annoying.

Can't you use the Set Material Index and Material Index nodes to set and get the materials by their indices?

@Blunder I experimented with those nodes, but nothing I tried worked.

have you assigned the base object (the one with the GN modifier) some materials? The index is related to the material slots.

@Blunder Yes, I did.

Oh, sorry, I see. The (Set) Material Index nodes only work for the base mesh and not for geometry created by GN. -- But can't you just assign a few materials to the base object and use a Set Material node with a group input for the material? Then you can choose the material in the GN modifier setting. Where and why do you need a Get Material node? (does not exist)

@Blunder I'm just annoyed by having to switch between the Shading and Geometry Nodes views, and was hoping there would be a way to just set up the Geometry Nodes once and be done with it before moving on to the materials work.
